# Navbar breaking in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a web portfolio for myself. Everything was fine while I was viewing it on my Desktop, but the issue happens when I view it on my phone.

a) The navbar collapses but it is not aligned properly.
b) There is some space on the right side of the viewport on my hero section. I am trying to understand the error but to no avail.

Link to portfolio: https://smammar.netlify.app/

**HTML code**

```
<header class="navigation fixed-top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand font-tertiary h3" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="logo"
style="width: 130px; height: 130px;"> </a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation"
aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="responsiveNav">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navigation">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="about.html">about</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
<!-- hero area -->
<section class="hero-area bg-primary" id="parallax">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
<h2 class="text-white font-tertiary">Hi! I’m <br> Syed Mohammad Ammar <br> Full-Stack Designer</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="layer" id="l2">
<img src="images/illustrations/dots-cyan.png" alt="bg-shape">
</div>
<div class="layer" id="l4">
<img src="images/illustrations/dots-orange.png" alt="bg-shape">
</div>
<div class="layer" id="l6">
<img src="images/illustrations/dots-group-cyan.png" alt="illustrations" class="bg-shape-6">
</div>
<div class="layer" id="l9">
<img src="images/illustrations/dots-orange.png" alt="bg-shape">
</div>
<!-- social icon -->
<ul class="list-unstyled ml-5 mt-3 position-relative zindex-1">
<li class="mb-3"><a class="text-white" href="https://twitter.com/SMAmmar5"><i class="fab fa-github"
id="socialIcons"></i></a></li>
<li class="mb-3"><a class="text-white" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter" id="socialIcons1"></i></a></li>
<li class="mb-3"><a class="text-white" href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance" id="socialIcons2"></i></a></li>
<li class="mb-3"><a class="text-white" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" id="socialIcons3"></i></i></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /social icon -->
</section>
<!-- /hero area -->
<!-- about -->
<section class="section">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto text-center">
<p class="font-secondary paragraph-lg text-dark">I'm a full-stack designer based in Karachi, <span style="color: #228B22"> Pakistan </span> with
experience in delivering end-to-end UX/UI design to complete website for software products. I'm passionate about improving the
lives of others by creating human centric products.</p>
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/.../syed%20mohammad%20ammar.pdf..." class="btn "
id="viewResume">View Resume</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.navigation {
padding: 40px 100px;
transition: .3s ease;
}
.navigation.nav-bg {
background-color: #000
;
padding: 0 70px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.navigation.nav-bg {
padding: 15px 20px;
}
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.navigation {
padding: 20px;
background: #000
;
}
}
.navbar .nav-item .nav-link {
font-family: "BwNistaInt-xBd";
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 15px;
}
.navbar .nav-item.active {
font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
color: #fff;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
border-color: #ffa500;
color: #ffa500;
box-shadow: 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.5em #ffa500;
transition: all 0.2s;
cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-area {
padding: 300px 0 200px;
position: relative;
}
.hero-area h2 {
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
.layer {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
#l1 {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
#l2 {
top: 190px;
left: -250px;
}
#l3 {
top: 200px;
left: 40%;
}
#l4 {
top: 200px;
right: 40%;
}
#l5 {
top: 100px;
right: -150px;
}
#l6 {
bottom: -20px;
left: 10%;
}
#l7 {
bottom: 100px;
left: 20%;
}
#l8 {
bottom: 160px;
right: 45%;
}
#l9 {
bottom: 100px;
right: -10px;
}
.layer-bg {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix. Try to add this into your css this will remove the spacing and improper alignments in responsive mode.

```
body, html {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It is working fine. But another issue is that the toggle button is stacking below the logo instead of staying inline.

Comment: try to add `float:right` on your `navbar-toggler`. I can't reproduce the issue because it is totally working on my end when I view it.

Comment: Thank you for the help it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the header tag & it's class and then add 'fixed-top' class to the nav tag. That might solve the issue.

Comment: You are not using bootstrap throughout the page, so it's not clear. If you can share your custom CSS, it gives an idea of where the problem is.